# Incorporating Bootstrap4 Theme in a Ruby Rails website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, themes, bootstrap-4

I am fairly new to Rails and Bootstrap. I am struggling to incorporate Bootstrap4 Theme in a Ruby Rails website. **All white space with some text is displayed when I try.**
I have installed the BS4 bootstrap-rubygem. Infact the application website & all the basic BS Styling works fine with default stuff in place. However I have little luck in incorporation [this Bootswatch Flatly Theme](https://bootswatch.com/flatly/) as I quite like this styling. [On this page for Flatly Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/) it gives you 6 files to download i.e bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.css, variables.less, bootswatch.less, _variables.sass, _bootswatch.sass. I assume I only need the sass files which begins with underscore in filename. So I have put these 2 files in assets/stylesheets folder. There are no js files to download on website so am I ok to assume that I don't need js files for assets/javascripts folder? So I have no js files pasted anywhere.
Here is my setup:
Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

#Added by me
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'
end

# Added by MS
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '~> 3.2', '>= 3.2.1'
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OmegaBlog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
      <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

application.scss (should this be called application.css.scss? and the order of @import items correct?? - I have doubt on this)

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "variables";
@import "bootswatch";
```

application.js (again not confident on order of listed items here!)

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

So the problem is that the Navbar is all white which only some text visible:

```
<div class="bs-docs-section clearfix">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="page-header">
              <h1 id="navbar">Navbar</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="bs-component">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                  </div>

                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
```

I have searched for basic instructions for detailed BS4 with Rails 5.1 but no luck!!

Comment: have you checked the javascript inspector to see if any of the css files 404 and also done control shift r to refresh the page cache?

Comment: No js errors or 404s. However it looks like it does not hit my custom sasses. I am playing around with the order of things in application.scss. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those themes are built for the Bootstrap 3.X, though you are using `bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.beta'`.

FYI https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/issues/499

Comment: Great! I had this feeling too, because as when I was playing around with the order of things in application.scss,  then only my _bootswatch.scss & _variables.scss got used (after reporting this problem here). This was confirmed by rails server's usual error saying "undefined variable $brand-success !important" Hence it looks like this could be BS version incompatibility. Thank you!!

Comment: It's my pleasure. :)

Comment: Now, I will try and use the 2 files _bootswatch.scss & _variables.scss from [Git Repo for Flatly BS4 Alpha6](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/tree/v4.0.0-alpha.6/flatly)